# Reverse/Undo .EPF Eclipse Prefrences Import

Tags: eclipse, themes

I have imported a .EPF Eclipse preferences file [from here](http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/?view=theme&id=8125) via `File > Import > General > Preferences`. The preferences file changes the colorization for the TeXlipse editor.

How do I remove/reverse the changes that this .EPF import has made?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can reverse these theme color changes in one of two ways:

**GUI Method**

- *Short Instructions*: Navigate to `Window -> Preferences`.  In the popup that is displayed, expand the menu for the language you're interested in (in this example, it will be Java).  Navigate to `Java -> Editor -> Syntax Coloring`.  Click the `Restore Defaults` button.  Click the `Apply` button.
- *Step-by-step*:

  1. Click on the **Window** button on the toolbar.
  2. Select the **Preferences** option from the subsequent drop-down menu.
  3. In the window that is displayed next, click on the arrow to the left of **Java** (or whatever language you are interested in changing the settings for).
  4. Click on the arrow to the left of the subsequent **Editor** option.
  5. Click on the subsequent **Syntax Coloring** option.
  6. At the bottom right of the window, click the **Restore Defaults** button.
  7. Next to it, click the **Apply** button.
  8. The default coloration for this language should now be restored.  If it's not, you can try the second method.

**Screenshots**

[image: window->preferences]

[image: restore defaults]

**Direct Method**

Your preferences are stored in a directory in the workspace.  Its relative path is `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings`.  If you delete everything in this directory and restart Eclipse, all settings will be reverted to their default values.  (Note: ***all*** settings, not just necessarily the ones you're interested in.)  Alternatively, you can try deleting specific `.prefs` files in an attempt to isolate the specific preferences to reset (for example, `org.eclipse.ui.prefs` and `org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs` seem promising, but I haven't tested this).

Also, since these preferences are workspace-specific, you can simply create a new workspace and move your existing projects to it.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't manage to directly reverse the effects of the import but to change the colorization I downloaded the [Eclipse Colorer plugin](http://colorer.sourceforge.net/eclipsecolorer/index.html) which worked a treat.